# Loading glb model in react native three using expo-three component not working on android device. The model appears on the web version though

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to create a react-native apps with three js using expo-gl, expo-three frameworks.

Following is the list of imports..

```
import { ExpoWebGLRenderingContext, GLView } from 'expo-gl';
import ExpoTHREE, { Renderer, TextureLoader } from 'expo-three';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import * as React from 'react';
import {
AmbientLight,
HemisphereLight,
BoxBufferGeometry,
Fog,
GridHelper,
Mesh,
MeshStandardMaterial,
PerspectiveCamera,
PointLight,
Scene,
SpotLight,
Camera,
InstancedMesh,
} from 'three';
import OrbitControlsView from 'expo-three-orbit-controls';
```

Apart from the basic scene, camera and light setup I'm trying to load a glb model using the ExpoTHREE.loadAsync method as below...

```
const loadGlb = async ()=>{
   const obj = await ExpoTHREE.loadAsync(
   [require('./assets/suzanne.glb')],
   null,
   null}).
   then((e)=>{
       scene.add(e.scene);
       e.scene.traverse((f)=>{if(f.isMesh){f.material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();}});
   })
   .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)});
   }
   
   loadGlb();
```

Using the ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-three

The model loads when I run the code on the desktop browser but not on my android phone using expo app. Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

[image: The model loads on browser version]
[image: The model not loading on android app using expo]
[image: One warning message]

You can access the app here https://expo.io/@praful124/expo3

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and ended up running into the fact that it does not support textures inside the glb file. But if you find a solution, I will be very happy if you share them.

Comment: I am now trying to display a model using a WebView, try this option too

Comment: I was not using any texture on the model actually, but yea WebView using PhoneGap seems to be a better option to go native with three.js application.